# Showing $x\sim_{\phi}y$ iff $x\sim_\pi y$ iff $x\sim_N y$ and more.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is Exercise 2.7.1 of F. M. Goodman's *"Algebra: Abstract and Concrete"*.

> **Exercise 2.7.1:** Let $\phi: G\to \bar{G}$ be a surjective homomorphism with kernel $N$. Let $\pi: G\to G/N$ be the quotient homomorphism. Show that for $x, y\in G$,
>   $$x\sim_{\phi}y\Leftrightarrow x\sim_{\pi}y\Leftrightarrow x\sim_Ny.$$ Conclude that the map $\bar{\phi}: G/N\to \bar{G}$ given by $\bar{\phi}(aN)=\phi(a)$ is well-defined and bijective.

Here $\sim_{\psi}$ is the equivalence relation given by $\psi$.

### My Attempt:

Let $x, y\in G$. Then

$$\begin{align}
x\sim_{\phi}y &\Leftrightarrow \phi(x)=\phi(y) \\
&\Leftrightarrow \phi(xy^{-1})=e_{\bar{G}} \\
&\Leftrightarrow xN=yN \\
&\Leftrightarrow x\sim_\pi y \\
&\Leftrightarrow xN=yN \\
&\Leftrightarrow x\sim_N y.
\end{align}$$

Is this right? I don't know what to do next.

Comment: In what you have done you have shown that $\bar{\phi}$ is well-defined and injective. It is surjective as $\phi$ and $\pi$ are.

Comment: @user152874 Ah, of course! Thank you. That would work as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments:

> "In what you have done you have shown that $\bar{\phi}$ is well-defined and injective. It is surjective as $\phi$ and $\pi$ are."

Comment: @user152874 I've put this as an answer for you.